# Copy and pasting problems in Tinn R

Tags: tinn-r

I am running Tinn-R version 3.0.2.7 on a windows 8 machine and I cannot copy or paste into the text editor. However, it will let me copy into the R console. It is in editing not read only mode. When I use ctrl+c -> ctrl+v the editor indicates that the script has been changed (I get an * on the file tab indicating that the version has not been saved) but it does not paste the copied selected content. I have searched the help file, but could not find a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tinn-R project has a user list (discussion group) on Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/tinn-r